# How to set bold italic underline in Quill by using simple JavaScript without DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, quill, rich-text-editor

I want to apply rich-text editor format by using a simple javascript function. In Quill I am not using any DOM element for bold italic underline. I don't want to include the toolbar module in Quill. Normally we use    `document.execCommand('bold', false, null);` in JavaScript to enable disable bold formatting.
Is there any comment in Quill to achieve this format without using the toolbar module?

Comment: Did you look at the api? https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#formattext

Comment: @epascarello Thank you for the quick reply.  formattext  function require to start index and length to apply format. Instead of the above, I used the shorthand method to apply the format from JavaScript this.quill.format('bold',true).  This might will help other.

Comment: @Dhanraja check bellow link , as font is used 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/quill-example-pt